# rewrite a multiple level URL and placing a query string at the end

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to add a query string to all 2nd and 3rd level URLs on a website that doesn't contain a query string.

At the moment I am here:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?features_hash=314-44914 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Which only redirects the home page from https://www.website.com/ to https://www.website.com/?features_hash=314-44914

All other levels get redirected to home.

I also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ /?features_hash=314-44914 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Which Only works on the homepage and the rest of the tree ignores it. No change there.
I need to have

- https://www.website.com/L1 to https://www.website.com/L1/?features_hash=314-44914
- https://www.website.com/L1/L2 to https://www.website.com/L1/L2/?features_hash=314-44914
- https://www.website.com/L1/L2/L3 to https://www.website.com/L1/L2/L3/?features_hash=314-44914

and so on

Basically I don't mind if the query is added on the front page. Doesn't make any difference. I need it though on the 2nd 3rd and 4th levels. Actually on all levels of the website.

So the solution suggested still doesn't work. It looks correct but doesn't work at the moment. It redirects all URLs to home with the query. So the URL levels are lost and collapse all to home.

So I figured there might be an issue with the rest of the rewrite conditions in htacess. Maybe the whole file can help:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^init.php$ - [F,L,NC]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(favicon|apple-touch-icon-|homescreen-|firefox-icon-|coast-icon-|mstile-).*\.(png|ico)$ - [R=404,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^api/(.*)$ [or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/api/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*api/(.*)$ api.php?_d=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|gif|ico|swf|jpe?g|js|css|ttf|svg|eot|woff|yml|xml)$ [NC,or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} store_closed.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\/(.*)$ $2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]

# Solution Suggested by anubhava - Thank you!
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)features_hash= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?features_hash=314-44914 [L,R=301,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use generic redirect rule for this to add `features_hash=314-44914` if query parameter `features_hash` doesn't exist:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)features_hash= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?features_hash=314-44914 [L,R=301,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: That gives me an internal server error.
is that line

Comment: sorry there was an extra character after `=` and I have removed it now. Please try again.

Comment: Ok now. No more intenal server error. However, I'm still back in square one. I still get redirected to www.website.com/?features_hash=314-44914 with any URL level I choose.
For example  www.website.com/baby/shoes redirects to www.website.com/?features_hash=314-44914

Comment: With this rule `www.website.com/baby/shoes` will be redirected to `www.website.com/baby/shoes?features_hash=314-44914`. You browser may be having old cache. Test in a new browser or completely clear browser cache.

Comment: I tried again and with a different browser. I cleared cache and turned on development mode.
Didn't work. I figure that it might be a conflict with the rest of the htaccess rewrite rules. So I'm posting the whole htaccess file (just the part with the rewrite rules) and I have the solution you suggested at the end.

I still redirects everything to home adding the query at the end.

Comment: I also added it here: http://beta.computerspot.gr/ and since it's a beta I can keep it that way till we figure it out. It's a grav-based page and I get the same issue there too. Only all pages get redirected to http://beta.computerspot.gr/index.php?features_hash=314-44914.
Except this one: http://beta.computerspot.gr/rig-profits which leads to a folder not part of the grav CMS.
So final conclusion: the code you suggested works but it seems to not work as intended when the URL is handled and redirected by a CMS.

Comment: Oh DAMN!!! it Worked!
I moved the solution at the top of the redirect rules and it worked!
Great job! Thank you!
Now... for SEO's sake and to have more clear URLs is it possible to make this redirection happen only on 2nd level URLs? Not the home page?
So have www.website.com clear - no redirection and add the query to every added level Ex www.website.com/shoes/?features_hash=314-44914?

Have a suggestion for that?

Comment: Indeed redirect rules should be placed at top of .htaccess

Comment: Redirect rules were on top, however your solution was placed at the bottom at first. As you see on my initial post. However, When I moved the 2 lines you suggested right below the RewriteEngine on directive, magic happened.
you think you might have a suggestion to apply that rule on all pages EXCEPT the homepage?

Comment: If you want to avoid home page then use: `RewriteRule .` instead of `RewriteRule ^`